# "dotnet ef database update" programatically with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'd like to call these migrations from a script and while there's plenty of information on how to do that with Entity Framework standard there's very little with Entity Framework Core.

I believe that this is the command that I need but I'm not sure on how to instantiate it properly or where the underlying classes are.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/7c64310a66ad04d04c43edaa70dc9e3963cb493f/src/ef/Commands/DatabaseUpdateCommand.Configure.cs

Edit: There seems to be some confusion about what it is I'm trying to do. Here is an example in the standard Entity Framework. However, upon first look there doesn't seem to be equivilent to `DbMigrator` in entity framework core.

https://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Comment: Do you mean running `Update-Database` from Package Manager Console?

Comment: No. I mean calling it from a script I wrote myself. Not from the CLI.

Comment: Do you mean run pending migrations in `Startup`?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We made it easier in EF Core:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    db.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful mate. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: The official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#applying-migrations-at-runtime